# Load featured slider images without crop in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am currently building my first ever WordPress based website. I am using [Bold Photography Theme](https://de.wordpress.org/themes/bold-photography/), of which I have already created a child theme. I have activated the featured slider option in 'Theme Options', which loops through couple of pages I have selected.

The problem is that images from the pages are being cropped, which I want to avoid. Shouldn't WordPress (or PHP?) automatically scale the images to fit the screen?

I would actually not want the **un-cropped images** in the slider take up the whole screen, but leave a margin around the images, so that I can see the homepage behind.

There is a `post-type-slider.php`

```php
<?php

$quantity     = get_theme_mod( 'bold_photography_slider_number', 4 );
$no_of_post   = 0; // for number of posts
$post_list    = array(); // list of valid post/page ids
$show_content = get_theme_mod( 'bold_photography_slider_content_show', 'hide-content' );

$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'any',
    'orderby'             => 'post__in',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, // ignore sticky posts
);

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++ ) {
        $post_id = '';

        $post_id = get_theme_mod( 'bold_photography_slider_page_' . $i );

        if ( $post_id && '' !== $post_id ) {
            $post_list = array_merge( $post_list, array( $post_id ) );

            $no_of_post++;
        }
    }

    $args['post__in'] = $post_list;


if ( ! $no_of_post ) {
    return;
}

$args['posts_per_page'] = $no_of_post;

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();

    $classes = 'post post-' . get_the_ID() . ' hentry slides';
    
    $thumbnail = 'post-thumbnail';
    ?>
    <article class="<?php echo esc_attr( $classes ); ?>">
        <div class="hentry-inner">
            <?php bold_photography_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail, 'html', true, true ); ?>
            
            <div class="entry-container">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h2 class="entry-title">
                        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </header>

                <?php
                if ( 'excerpt' === $show_content ) {
                    echo '<div class="entry-summary"><p>' . wp_kses_post( get_the_excerpt() ) . '</p></div><!-- .entry-summary -->';
                } elseif ( 'full-content' === $show_content ) {
                    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
                    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
                    echo '<div class="entry-content">' . wp_kses_post( $content ) . '</div><!-- .entry-content -->';
                } 
                ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-container -->
        </div><!-- .hentry-inner -->
    </article><!-- .slides -->
<?php
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

and there are `feature-slider` elements in `style.css`

```css
/**
 * 14.1 - Slider
 */

#feature-slider-section {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#feature-slider-section .wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

#feature-slider-section .hentry {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#feature-slider-section .hentry-inner {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 100px 30px;
    position: relative;
}

#feature-slider-section .post-thumbnail {
    margin: 0;
    position: unset;
}

#feature-slider-section .post-thumbnail img {
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 1000%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}

@supports (object-fit: cover) {
    #feature-slider-section .post-thumbnail img {
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        object-fit: cover;
        top: 0;
        transform: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

#feature-slider-section .entry-container {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 80px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .4s;
    -o-transition-delay: .4s;
    -ms-transition-delay: .4s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
    z-index: 9;
}

#feature-slider-section .active .entry-container {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    left: 0;
}

#feature-slider-section .entry-container > * {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#feature-slider-section .entry-container > * > * {
    max-width: 470px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#feature-slider-section .entry-title {
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
}

#feature-slider-section .entry-summary,
#feature-slider-section .entry-content {
    display: none;
}
```

**Edit 1:** `bold_photography_post_thumbnail` function

```
function bold_photography_post_thumbnail( $image_size = 'post-thumbnail', $type = 'html', $echo = true, $no_thumb = false ) {
        $image = $image_url = '';
        
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), $image_size );
            $image     = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $image_size );
        } else {
            if ( $no_thumb ) {
                global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

                $image_url  = trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/images/no-thumb-' . $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $image_size ]['width'] . 'x' . $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $image_size ]['height'] . '.jpg';
                $image      = '<img src="' . esc_url( $image_url ) . '" alt="" />';
            }

            // Get the first image in page, returns false if there is no image.
            $first_image_url = bold_photography_get_first_image( get_the_ID(), $image_size, '', true );

            // Set value of image as first image if there is an image present in the page.
            if ( $first_image_url ) {
                $image_url = $first_image_url;
                $image = '<img class="wp-post-image" src="'. esc_url( $image_url ) .'">';
            }
        }

        if ( ! $image_url ) {
            // Bail if there is no image url at this stage.
            return;
        }

        if ( 'url' === $type ) {
            return $image_url;
        }

        $output = '<div';

        if ( 'html-with-bg' === $type ) {
            $output .= ' class="post-thumbnail-background" style="background-image: url( ' . esc_url( $image_url ) . ' )"';
        } else {
            $output .= ' class="post-thumbnail"';
        }

        $output .= '>';

        if ( 'html-with-bg' !== $type ) {
            $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">' . $image;
        } else {
            $output .= '<a class="cover-link" href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">';
        }

        $output .= '</a></div><!-- .post-thumbnail -->';

        if ( ! $echo ) {
            return $output;
        }

        echo $output;
    }
```

Comment: What does this `bold_photography_post_thumbnail` do?  This function gets the slide? That would be where you could adjust the size.

Comment: I have updated the question with the function. But what about the image getting cropped?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input above, all you need to do is either update this

```
$thumbnail = 'post-thumbnail';
```

to

```
$thumbnail = 'full';
```

Or you can simplify by updating from this.

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();

    $classes = 'post post-' . get_the_ID() . ' hentry slides';

    $thumbnail = 'post-thumbnail';
    ?>
    <article class="<?php echo esc_attr( $classes ); ?>">
        <div class="hentry-inner">
            <?php bold_photography_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail, 'html', true, true ); ?>
```

to this:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();

    $classes = 'post post-' . get_the_ID() . ' hentry slides';
    ?>
    <article class="<?php echo esc_attr( $classes ); ?>">
        <div class="hentry-inner">
            <?php bold_photography_post_thumbnail( 'full', 'html', true, true ); ?>
```

Using this will return the "Full Width" uncropped image.  Whether or not it displays at 100% width would be a function of the CSS.

Comment: unfortunately this does not change anything

Comment: It should do something.  It should return the full sized image.  There's no way to test this without having your configuration, so you should check the returned image and see if it is in fact the full sized image.